# NgRx - Multiple actions are being dispatch during the router transition

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I've implemented the route resolver intended to request some data before navigating to the new route. Here is the piece of code responsible for dispatching the action to the store:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData());
        }),
        first()
      );
  }
}
```

After hitting appropriate route and trigerring the resolver, I can see from Redux DevTools that my action has been dispatched twice before the navigation occured.

[image]

Well, my assumption then was that this is because of `ROUTER_REQUEST` and `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` being dispatched during the same router transition that causes the store to emit twice, in response to each dispatched action accordingly. However, if I comment out the line which dispatches the action and put there `console.log` instead, like so:

```js
tap(() => {
    // this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData());
    console.log('Dispatching action');
  })
```

Router Store will still fire `ROUTER_REQUEST` and `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` actions but this time around the store will emit only once, as well as the test message is going to be outputted to the console just the one time.

How does the action dispatch make the difference?

Doesn't `ROUTER_REQUEST` and `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` actions matter in this situation?

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y23xcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy%2Flazy.resolver.ts) you can run.

Comment: Is that action `loadSomeData` also the result of any effect ?

Comment: No, it's not. I will try to provide a demo on StackBlitz a little later.

Comment: @andrei-gătej, I have updated the post with StackBlitz demo and thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a closer look tomorrow. I think the router is the culprit, since after removing the `StoreDevtoolsModule`, it would still log twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there's no 'culprit' here.

This behavior is the result of how NgRx is using RxJS' entities.

The `Store` entity is an **observable** whose `source` is set to `state$`(the `State` entity - where data is stored):

```js
export class Store<T = object> extends Observable<T>
  implements Observer<Action> {
  constructor(
    state$: StateObservable,
    private actionsObserver: ActionsSubject,
    private reducerManager: ReducerManager
  ) {
    super();

    this.source = state$;
  }
}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L20)

This implies that every subscriber that subscribes to `store`(e.g: `lazy.resolver` - `this.store.pipe(...)`), will actually subscribe to `State`, [which is a `BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/state.ts#L19), meaning that the subscriber will be part of the **subscribers list** maintained by this subject.

As you know, a `BehaviorSubject` sends the latest *nexted value* to the new subscriber. This is pointed out by the first time that messaged is logged.

The reason that message is logged twice is because whenever you **dispatch** an **action**, a couple of things take place inside `State`.
The action will be `intercepted` in state, and when it happens, all the reducers will be invoked with the **current state** and the **current action**, resulting into a **new state** which is immediately **sent** to its **subscribers**:

```js
// Inside `State.ts`

// Actions stream
const actionsOnQueue$: Observable<Action> = actions$.pipe(
  observeOn(queueScheduler)
);

// Making sure everything happens after the reducers have been set up
const withLatestReducer$: Observable<
  [Action, ActionReducer<any, Action>]
> = actionsOnQueue$.pipe(withLatestFrom(reducer$));

const seed: StateActionPair<T> = { state: initialState }; // Default state
const stateAndAction$: Observable<{
  state: any;
  action?: Action;
}> = withLatestReducer$.pipe(
  scan<[Action, ActionReducer<T, Action>], StateActionPair<T>>(
    reduceState, // Calling the reducers, resulting in a new state
    seed
  )
);

this.stateSubscription = stateAndAction$.subscribe(({ state, action }) => {
  this.next(state); // Send the new state to the subscribers(e.g in lazy.resolver)
  scannedActions.next(action); // Send the action so that it can be intercepted by the effects
});
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/state.ts#L32-L53)

So when the `store` is initially subscribed, it will send its latest stored value, but when you dispatch another action(like) you do inside `tap`'s next callback, a new state will be sent to the subscribers, which should explain why you're getting that messaged logged twice.

You might wonder how come we don't get into an infinite loop. These lines prevent that:

```js
const actionsOnQueue$: Observable<Action> = actions$.pipe(
  observeOn(queueScheduler)
);
```

`observeOn(queueScheduler)` is very important here. Whenever an action is dispatched(e.g `this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData());`) it will not just pass along the action immediately(although it's using the `queueScheduler`), but it will **schedule an action** that will have to do some work(the `work` in this case is the task to pass along the action).

But when you do `this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData());`, it will reach the `this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData());` again and before it reaches `first()`.

I guess this is why is called **queue**Scheduler; you're not getting an infinite loop error because the `asyncScheduler`(from which `queueScheduler` inherits) will make sure that if the **scheduler** is **active**(an action is doing its work, for example the first `this.store.dispatch(loadSomeData())`), the newly arrived action will be added to a queue, and will be taken into account when the active action finishes its work:

```js
const { actions } = this;

if (this.active) {
  actions.push(action);
  return;
}

let error: any;
this.active = true;

do {
  if (error = action.execute(action.state, action.delay)) {
    break;
  }
} while (action = actions.shift()!); // exhaust the scheduler queue
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/state.ts#L32-L53)

And because you're using `first()` and `take(5)`, you're making sure than after an action finishes its work(e.g pushing the value further into the stream), the next action in queue won't have any effect, because, in this case, `first()` or `take(5)` would be reached **before** any actions in queue get the chance to perform their task.

---

If you'd like to read more about how `ngrx/store` works internally, I'd recommend having a look at [Understanding the magic behind StoreModule of NgRx (@ngrx/store)](https://indepth.dev/understanding-the-magic-behind-ngrx-store/)